# How to request the schema from a GraphQL service using curl?

Tags: graphql

I have a curl script (as a standin for real code) that can POST to my company's GraphQL endoint and get data. It's working fine.

It appears that it should also be possible to get the "schema" by crafting the appropriate request, but I have not found any way to do that at a HTTP level.

If it is possible, what would the curl look like (the data)?

Are there other requests other than "query" that I can use to gleen other information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The body you need is pretty involved for an introspection query, but I think you're looking for something like this

introspection_query.json:

```
{ 
  "query": "query IntrospectionQuery {
      __schema {
        queryType { name }
        mutationType { name }
        subscriptionType { name }
        types {
          ...FullType
        }
        directives {
          name
          description
          locations
          args {
            ...InputValue
          }
        }
      }
    }

    fragment FullType on __Type {
      kind
      name
      description
      fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
        name
        description
        args {
          ...InputValue
        }
        type {
          ...TypeRef
        }
        isDeprecated
        deprecationReason
      }
      inputFields {
        ...InputValue
      }
      interfaces {
        ...TypeRef
      }
      enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
        name
        description
        isDeprecated
        deprecationReason
      }
      possibleTypes {
        ...TypeRef
      }
    }

    fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
      name
      description
      type { ...TypeRef }
      defaultValue
    }

    fragment TypeRef on __Type {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
                ofType {
                  kind
                  name
                  ofType {
                    kind
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }"
}
```

and then you can do

```
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8080/graphql -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @introspection_query.json
```

Shamefully stolen from
https://gist.github.com/martinheld/9fe32b7e2c8fd932599d36e921a2a825

Comment: Introspection queries like these are the only way to get a JSON representation of the schema from the GraphQL service itself. But if you want to turn that into an actual schema object in the programming language of your choice, there's probably a function for that. For example, the JavaScript reference implementation has [this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/af480089b5fcaa961adb356ef1dca13cf475e75f/src/utilities/buildClientSchema.js).

Comment: I'm very happy you stole this! I would never have found it on my own and it never occurred to me to search on GraphQL and introspection (face palm!).

Comment: I just read this against my API and it worked!!! A request to anyone who finds this of interest: please visit the GitHub link above and Star the gist. Really, there wasn't a single star until I added one.

Comment: Although line breaks are not allowed in .json files (for valid json you need to replace spaces with \n) this code still worked, thanks.